# Creating a noise distortion along the edges of an object only (for a hologram effect)

Tags: modifiers, weight-painting

I'm trying to make a distortion/glitch effect driven by noise along the edges of my object. I'll cut the mesh in half to just have the front face, and then I want to push back the outlining vertexes behind the mesh randomly based on the noise. So, if the mesh is animated to say, turn its head, it's almost like the parts of the face that are turned that direction are being pulled backwards like a magnet.

I would assume weight proximity editing with an empty placed a distance behind the subject would help, but I am relatively new to dynamic painting. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

[image]